# cannot install Postgres on windows 8.1

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to install postgres so I can use it with my rails app. I downloaded the installer for postgres 9.3. At the end of the installation process the following warning popped up

```
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. Error reading file C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data\postgresql.conf
```

I am fairly new to anything database related (been using default sqlite for rails), so if you can provide a detailed explanation that would be very much appreciated

The following is from install-postgresql.log

```
Log started 07/28/2014 at 19:52:53
Preferred installation mode : qt
Trying to init installer in mode qt
Mode qt successfully initialized
Executing C:\Users\Jack Hou\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_32baa80030/temp_check_comspec.bat 
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 "test ok"

Script stderr:


Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.3 Data Directory. Setting variable iDataDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.3 Base Directory. Setting variable iBaseDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.3 Service ID. Setting variable iServiceName to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.3 Service Account. Setting variable iServiceAccount to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.3 Super User. Setting variable iSuperuser to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.3 Branding. Setting variable iBranding to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.3 Version. Setting variable brandingVer to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.3 Shortcuts. Setting variable iShortcut to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.3 DisableStackBuilder. Setting variable iDisableStackBuilder to empty value
[19:52:57] Existing base directory: 
[19:52:57] Existing data directory: 
[19:52:57] Using branding: PostgreSQL 9.3
[19:52:57] Using Super User: postgres and Service Account: NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
[19:52:57] Using Service Name: postgresql-x64-9.3
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Users\Jack Hou\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_32baa80030\prerun_checks.vbs"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 The scripting host appears to be functional.

Script stderr:


Executing C:\Users\Jack Hou\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_32baa80030\vcredist_x64.exe /passive /norestart
Script exit code: 0

Script output:


Script stderr:


Executing C:\Users\Jack Hou\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_32baa80030\getlocales.exe 
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 AfrikaansxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=Afrikaans, South Africa
AlbanianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAlbania=Albanian, Albania
AlsatianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFrance=Alsatian, France
AmharicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEthiopia=Amharic, Ethiopia
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAlgeria=Arabic, Algeria
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBahrain=Arabic, Bahrain
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEgypt=Arabic, Egypt
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIraq=Arabic, Iraq
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxJordan=Arabic, Jordan
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxKuwait=Arabic, Kuwait
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLebanon=Arabic, Lebanon
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLibya=Arabic, Libya
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMorocco=Arabic, Morocco
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxOman=Arabic, Oman
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxQatar=Arabic, Qatar
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSaudixxSPxxArabia=Arabic, Saudi Arabia
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSyria=Arabic, Syria
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxTunisia=Arabic, Tunisia
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUxxDOTxxAxxDOTxxExxDOTxx=Arabic, U.A.E.
ArabicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxYemen=Arabic, Yemen
ArmenianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxArmenia=Armenian, Armenia
AssamesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Assamese, India
AzerbaijanixxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAzerbaijan=Azerbaijani (Cyrillic), Azerbaijan
AzerbaijanixxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAzerbaijan=Azerbaijani (Latin), Azerbaijan
BanglaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBangladesh=Bangla, Bangladesh
BanglaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Bangla, India
BashkirxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRussia=Bashkir, Russia
BasquexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSpain=Basque, Spain
BelarusianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBelarus=Belarusian, Belarus
BosnianxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBosniaxxSPxxandxxSPxxHerzegovina=Bosnian (Cyrillic), Bosnia and Herzegovina
BosnianxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBosniaxxSPxxandxxSPxxHerzegovina=Bosnian (Latin), Bosnia and Herzegovina
BretonxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFrance=Breton, France
BulgarianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBulgaria=Bulgarian, Bulgaria
BurmesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMyanmar=Burmese, Myanmar
CatalanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSpain=Catalan, Spain
CentralxxSPxxAtlasxxSPxxTamazightxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAlgeria=Central Atlas Tamazight (Latin), Algeria
CentralxxSPxxAtlasxxSPxxTamazightxxSPxxxxOBxxTifinaghxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMorocco=Central Atlas Tamazight (Tifinagh), Morocco
CentralxxSPxxKurdishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIraq=Central Kurdish, Iraq
CherokeexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUnitedxxSPxxStates=Cherokee, United States
ChinesexxSPxxxxOBxxSimplifiedxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxChina=Chinese (Simplified), China
ChinesexxSPxxxxOBxxSimplifiedxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSingapore=Chinese (Simplified), Singapore
ChinesexxSPxxxxOBxxTraditionalxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxHongxxSPxxKongxxSPxxSAR=Chinese (Traditional), Hong Kong SAR
ChinesexxSPxxxxOBxxTraditionalxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMacaoxxSPxxSAR=Chinese (Traditional), Macao SAR
ChinesexxSPxxxxOBxxTraditionalxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxTaiwan=Chinese (Traditional), Taiwan
CorsicanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFrance=Corsican, France
CroatianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCroatia=Croatian, Croatia
CroatianxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBosniaxxSPxxandxxSPxxHerzegovina=Croatian (Latin), Bosnia and Herzegovina
CzechxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCzechxxSPxxRepublic=Czech, Czech Republic
DanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxDenmark=Danish, Denmark
DarixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAfghanistan=Dari, Afghanistan
DivehixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMaldives=Divehi, Maldives
DutchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBelgium=Dutch, Belgium
DutchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNetherlands=Dutch, Netherlands
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAustralia=English, Australia
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBelize=English, Belize
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCanada=English, Canada
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCaribbean=English, Caribbean
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxHongxxSPxxKong=English, Hong Kong
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=English, India
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIreland=English, Ireland
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxJamaica=English, Jamaica
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMalaysia=English, Malaysia
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNewxxSPxxZealand=English, New Zealand
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPhilippines=English, Philippines
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSingapore=English, Singapore
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=English, South Africa
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxTrinidadxxSPxxandxxSPxxTobago=English, Trinidad and Tobago
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUnitedxxSPxxKingdom=English, United Kingdom
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUnitedxxSPxxStates=English, United States
EnglishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxZimbabwe=English, Zimbabwe
EstonianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEstonia=Estonian, Estonia
FaroesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFaroexxSPxxIslands=Faroese, Faroe Islands
FilipinoxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPhilippines=Filipino, Philippines
FinnishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFinland=Finnish, Finland
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBelgium=French, Belgium
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCameroon=French, Cameroon
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCanada=French, Canada
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCongoxxSPxx[DRC]=French, Congo [DRC]
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFrance=French, France
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxHaiti=French, Haiti
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIvoryxxSPxxCoast=French, Ivory Coast
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLuxembourg=French, Luxembourg
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMali=French, Mali
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMorocco=French, Morocco
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPrincipalityxxSPxxofxxSPxxMonaco=French, Principality of Monaco
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRéunion=French, Réunion
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSenegal=French, Senegal
FrenchxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSwitzerland=French, Switzerland
FrisianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNetherlands=Frisian, Netherlands
FulahxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSenegal=Fulah, Senegal
GalicianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSpain=Galician, Spain
GeorgianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGeorgia=Georgian, Georgia
GermanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAustria=German, Austria
GermanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGermany=German, Germany
GermanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLiechtenstein=German, Liechtenstein
GermanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLuxembourg=German, Luxembourg
GermanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSwitzerland=German, Switzerland
GreekxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGreece=Greek, Greece
GreenlandicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGreenland=Greenlandic, Greenland
GuaranixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxParaguay=Guarani, Paraguay
GujaratixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Gujarati, India
HausaxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNigeria=Hausa (Latin), Nigeria
HawaiianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUnitedxxSPxxStates=Hawaiian, United States
HebrewxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIsrael=Hebrew, Israel
HindixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Hindi, India
HungarianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxHungary=Hungarian, Hungary
IcelandicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIceland=Icelandic, Iceland
IgboxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNigeria=Igbo, Nigeria
IndonesianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndonesia=Indonesian, Indonesia
InuktitutxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCanada=Inuktitut (Latin), Canada
InuktitutxxSPxxxxOBxxSyllabicsxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCanada=Inuktitut (Syllabics), Canada
IrishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIreland=Irish, Ireland
ItalianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxItaly=Italian, Italy
ItalianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSwitzerland=Italian, Switzerland
JapanesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxJapan=Japanese, Japan
KannadaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Kannada, India
KazakhxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxKazakhstan=Kazakh, Kazakhstan
KhmerxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCambodia=Khmer, Cambodia
KinyarwandaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRwanda=Kinyarwanda, Rwanda
KiswahilixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxKenya=Kiswahili, Kenya
KonkanixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Konkani, India
KoreanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxKorea=Korean, Korea
KyrgyzxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxKyrgyzstan=Kyrgyz, Kyrgyzstan
LaoxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLaoxxSPxxPDR=Lao, Lao PDR
LatvianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLatvia=Latvian, Latvia
LithuanianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLithuania=Lithuanian, Lithuania
LowerxxSPxxSorbianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGermany=Lower Sorbian, Germany
LuxembourgishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLuxembourg=Luxembourgish, Luxembourg
MacedonianxxSPxxxxOBxxFormerxxSPxxYugoslavxxSPxxRepublicxxSPxxofxxSPxxMacedoniaxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMacedoniaxxSPxxxxOBxxFormerxxSPxxYugoslavxxSPxxRepublicxxSPxxofxxSPxxMacedoniaxxCBxx=Macedonian (Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia), Macedonia (Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia)
MalayalamxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Malayalam, India
MalayxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBruneixxSPxxDarussalam=Malay, Brunei Darussalam
MalayxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMalaysia=Malay, Malaysia
MaltesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMalta=Maltese, Malta
MaorixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNewxxSPxxZealand=Maori, New Zealand
MapudungunxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxChile=Mapudungun, Chile
MarathixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Marathi, India
MohawkxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCanada=Mohawk, Canada
MongolianxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMongolia=Mongolian (Cyrillic), Mongolia
MongolianxxSPxxxxOBxxTraditionalxxSPxxMongolianxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxChina=Mongolian (Traditional Mongolian), China
MongolianxxSPxxxxOBxxTraditionalxxSPxxMongolianxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMongolia=Mongolian (Traditional Mongolian), Mongolia
NepalixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Nepali, India
NepalixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNepal=Nepali, Nepal
NorwegianxxSPxxxxOBxxBokmålxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNorway=Norwegian (Bokmål), Norway
NorwegianxxSPxxxxOBxxNynorskxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNorway=Norwegian (Nynorsk), Norway
OccitanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFrance=Occitan, France
OdiaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Odia, India
OromoxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEthiopia=Oromo, Ethiopia
PashtoxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxAfghanistan=Pashto, Afghanistan
PersianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIran=Persian, Iran
PolishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPoland=Polish, Poland
PortuguesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBrazil=Portuguese, Brazil
PortuguesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPortugal=Portuguese, Portugal
PunjabixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Punjabi, India
PunjabixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPakistan=Punjabi, Pakistan
QuechuaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBolivia=Quechua, Bolivia
QuechuaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPeru=Quechua, Peru
QuichuaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEcuador=Quichua, Ecuador
RomanianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMoldova=Romanian, Moldova
RomanianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRomania=Romanian, Romania
RomanshxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSwitzerland=Romansh, Switzerland
RussianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRussia=Russian, Russia
SakhaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRussia=Sakha, Russia
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxInarixxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFinland=Sami (Inari), Finland
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxLulexxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNorway=Sami (Lule), Norway
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxLulexxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSweden=Sami (Lule), Sweden
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxNorthernxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFinland=Sami (Northern), Finland
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxNorthernxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNorway=Sami (Northern), Norway
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxNorthernxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSweden=Sami (Northern), Sweden
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxSkoltxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFinland=Sami (Skolt), Finland
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxSouthernxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNorway=Sami (Southern), Norway
SamixxSPxxxxOBxxSouthernxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSweden=Sami (Southern), Sweden
SanskritxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Sanskrit, India
ScottishxxSPxxGaelicxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUnitedxxSPxxKingdom=Scottish Gaelic, United Kingdom
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBosniaxxSPxxandxxSPxxHerzegovina=Serbian (Cyrillic), Bosnia and Herzegovina
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMontenegro=Serbian (Cyrillic), Montenegro
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSerbia=Serbian (Cyrillic), Serbia
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSerbiaxxSPxxandxxSPxxMontenegroxxSPxxxxOBxxFormerxxCBxx=Serbian (Cyrillic), Serbia and Montenegro (Former)
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBosniaxxSPxxandxxSPxxHerzegovina=Serbian (Latin), Bosnia and Herzegovina
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMontenegro=Serbian (Latin), Montenegro
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSerbia=Serbian (Latin), Serbia
SerbianxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSerbiaxxSPxxandxxSPxxMontenegroxxSPxxxxOBxxFormerxxCBxx=Serbian (Latin), Serbia and Montenegro (Former)
SesothoxxSPxxsaxxSPxxLeboaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=Sesotho sa Leboa, South Africa
SetswanaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBotswana=Setswana, Botswana
SetswanaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=Setswana, South Africa
SindhixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPakistan=Sindhi, Pakistan
SinhalaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSrixxSPxxLanka=Sinhala, Sri Lanka
SlovakxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSlovakia=Slovak, Slovakia
SlovenianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSlovenia=Slovenian, Slovenia
SomalixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSomalia=Somali, Somalia
SouthernxxSPxxSothoxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=Southern Sotho, South Africa
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxArgentina=Spanish, Argentina
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBolivarianxxSPxxRepublicxxSPxxofxxSPxxVenezuela=Spanish, Bolivarian Republic of Venezuela
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxBolivia=Spanish, Bolivia
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxChile=Spanish, Chile
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxColombia=Spanish, Colombia
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxCostaxxSPxxRica=Spanish, Costa Rica
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxDominicanxxSPxxRepublic=Spanish, Dominican Republic
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEcuador=Spanish, Ecuador
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxElxxSPxxSalvador=Spanish, El Salvador
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGuatemala=Spanish, Guatemala
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxHonduras=Spanish, Honduras
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxLatinxxSPxxAmerica=Spanish, Latin America
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxMexico=Spanish, Mexico
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNicaragua=Spanish, Nicaragua
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPanama=Spanish, Panama
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxParaguay=Spanish, Paraguay
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPeru=Spanish, Peru
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPuertoxxSPxxRico=Spanish, Puerto Rico
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSpain=Spanish, Spain
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSpain=Spanish, Spain
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUnitedxxSPxxStates=Spanish, United States
SpanishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUruguay=Spanish, Uruguay
SwedishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxFinland=Swedish, Finland
SwedishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSweden=Swedish, Sweden
SyriacxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSyria=Syriac, Syria
TajikxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxTajikistan=Tajik (Cyrillic), Tajikistan
TamilxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Tamil, India
TamilxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSrixxSPxxLanka=Tamil, Sri Lanka
TatarxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxRussia=Tatar, Russia
TeluguxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Telugu, India
ThaixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxThailand=Thai, Thailand
TibetanxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxChina=Tibetan, China
TigrinyaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEritrea=Tigrinya, Eritrea
TigrinyaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxEthiopia=Tigrinya, Ethiopia
TsongaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=Tsonga, South Africa
TurkishxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxTurkey=Turkish, Turkey
TurkmenxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxTurkmenistan=Turkmen, Turkmenistan
UkrainianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUkraine=Ukrainian, Ukraine
UpperxxSPxxSorbianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxGermany=Upper Sorbian, Germany
UrduxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxIndia=Urdu, India
UrduxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxPakistan=Urdu, Pakistan
UyghurxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxChina=Uyghur, China
UzbekxxSPxxxxOBxxCyrillicxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUzbekistan=Uzbek (Cyrillic), Uzbekistan
UzbekxxSPxxxxOBxxLatinxxCBxxxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUzbekistan=Uzbek (Latin), Uzbekistan
ValencianxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSpain=Valencian, Spain
VietnamesexxCOMMAxxxxSPxxVietnam=Vietnamese, Vietnam
WelshxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxUnitedxxSPxxKingdom=Welsh, United Kingdom
WolofxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSenegal=Wolof, Senegal
YixxCOMMAxxxxSPxxChina=Yi, China
YorubaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxNigeria=Yoruba, Nigeria
isiXhosaxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=isiXhosa, South Africa
isiZuluxxCOMMAxxxxSPxxSouthxxSPxxAfrica=isiZulu, South Africa

Script stderr:


Preparing to Install
Preparing to Install

....
....


Unpacking C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\symbols\zic.pdb
[19:53:58] Running the post-installation/upgrade actions:
[19:53:58] Write the base directory to the ini file...
[19:53:58] Write the version number to the ini file...
Initialising the database cluster (this may take a few minutes)...
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****" "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3" "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\data" 5432 "DEFAULT" 0
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 WScript.Shell Initialized...
Scripting.FileSystemObject initialized...

Called CreateDirectory(C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\data)...
Called CreateDirectory(C:\PostgreSQL\9.3)...
WScript.Network initialized...
strParentOfDataDirC:\PostgreSQL\9.3
logged in userJack\Jack
Called AclCheck(C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\data)
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.3
    MajorVersion:6
Executing icacls to ensure the Jack\Jack account can read the path C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\data
    Executing batch file 'radFC267.bat'...
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.3
    MajorVersion:6
Ensuring we can write to the data directory (using icacls) to  Jack\Jack:
    Executing batch file 'radFC267.bat'...
    Executing batch file 'radFC267.bat'...
Reading:    objConfFile is nothing...
Writing:    objConfFile is nothing...
Called AclCheck(C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\data)
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.3
    MajorVersion:6
Executing icacls to ensure the NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService account can read the path C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\data
    Executing batch file 'radFC267.bat'...
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.3
    MajorVersion:6
Granting service account access to the data directory (using icacls) to NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService:
    Executing batch file 'radFC267.bat'...
initcluster.vbs ran to completion

Script stderr:


Configuring database server startup...
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\installer\server\startupcfg.vbs" 9.3 "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "****" "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3" "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\data" "postgresql-x64-9.3"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 startupcfg.vbs ran to completion

Script stderr:


Creating menu shortcuts...
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\installer\server\createshortcuts.vbs" 9.3 "postgres" 5432 "PostgreSQL 9.3" "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3" "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\data" "postgresql-x64-9.3"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 Start FixupFile(C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\scripts\serverctl.vbs)...
   Opening file for reading...
   Closing file (reading)...
   Replacing placeholders...
   Opening file for writing...
   Closing file...
  End FixupFile()...
Start FixupFile(C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\scripts\runpsql.bat)...
   Opening file for reading...
   Closing file (reading)...
   Replacing placeholders...
   Opening file for writing...
   Closing file...
  End FixupFile()...
createshortcuts.vbs ran to completion

Script stderr:


Starting the database server...
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\installer\server\startserver.vbs" postgresql-x64-9.3
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 startserver.vbs ran to completion

Script stderr:


Loading additional SQL modules...
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\installer\server\loadmodules.vbs" "postgres" "****" "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3" "C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\data" 5432
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 Installing the adminpack module in the postgres database...
    Executing 'C:\Users\Jack Hou\AppData\Local\Temp\rad34749.bat'...
loadmodules.vbs ran to completion

Script stderr:


[19:54:05] Write the data directory to the ini file...
[19:54:05] Write the port number, service ID, locale and superuser to the ini file...
[19:54:05] Write ServiceID(postgresql-x64-9.3) to registry/ini...
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
 Error reading file C:/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/postgresql.conf
Creating Uninstaller
Creating uninstaller 25%
Creating uninstaller 50%
Creating uninstaller 75%
Creating uninstaller 100%
Installation completed
Log finished 07/28/2014 at 19:54:21
```

The pg_log file within my data file is empty

Comment: Please get the installer log and paste it here, or put it on pastebin or something and put a link here. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation

Comment: Most probably your are having permissions issue. First: try to install as an administrator. Second choose a folder different than c:\program files something like: c:\intalations\postgre

Comment: @Craig Ringer i've updated the question with install-postgresql.log. thanks for taking your time!

I installed it as an admin in my root C folder and it still retained the same problem

Comment: Try this then: http://forums.holdemmanager.com/general-support/150771-solved-postgresql-database-cluster-initialisation-failed.html

Comment: Also this one: http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/1891.page

Comment: both of the solution seems promising, but for the first link, I have windows 8.1 without the pro version so I cannot access Local User and Groups. For the second link, the solution keeps on mentioning a "postgres" account, but i ran net user on my command prompt and none of them is postgres

Comment: which framework(PostgreSQL Installer) you have downloaded `32bit` or `64bit` ?

Comment: I downladed the x64 version from http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows for version 9.3.5.1

Comment: The `postgres` account doesn't exist in the installer for PostgreSQL 9.2 or newer, it installs under `NETWORKSERVICE`. Do you have any group policy / are you on a domain? Any AV software?

Comment: hmm I do not thinkg i have any group policy. I disabled my AV when I tried to install postgres

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue under Windows 7 with Postgres 9.3.5 Installer (win-x64) and was able to fix it.

The issue seems to be a simple matter of invalid paths specified in one part of the install process. Here's the error log entry that shows the problem (around line 4000):

```
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program Files\Postgres\9.3/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****" "C:\postgres\9.3" "C:\Program Files\Postgres\9.3\data" 5432 "DEFAULT" 0
```

Note the forward slashes, which are not valid under Windows.
Rerunning the command with backslashes works great. Start a Windows Command Prompt as Administrator and run:

```
cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program Files\Postgres\9.3\installer\server\initcluster.vbs" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****" "C:\postgres\9.3" "C:\Program Files\Postgres\9.3\data" 5432 "DEFAULT" 0
```

Look through the installer log and re-run all the scripts that failed afterwards. They do have the right slashes so just copy and paste to run.